# AzerothCore DBand macOS: functions.sh: line 117: ${1,,}: bad substitution

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, mariadb, azerothcore

When trying to install the [AzerothCore Database](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Database-Setup) in macOS Catalina, using:

```
bash ./bin/acore-db-asm
```

I get the following error:

> azerothcore-wotlk/apps/db_assembler/includes/functions.sh: line 117: ${1,,}: bad substitution

Answer (score 0):

macOS comes by default with an older version of `bash`, that was causing the issue.

The script only works with bash 5 or newer, it can be installed using [brew]:

1. Run `brew install bash`
2. Restart the terminal
3. Make sure bash has now the right version using `bash --version`
4. Run the script. You might need to prefix it with `bash`, e.g. `bash ./bin/acore-db-asm`